# Segger J-Link Supply Adapter

Tags: swd, j-link

I have a microcontroller powered at 1.8V and I break out `V_target`, `SWD`, `SWCLK`, `nRST`, and `GND` from it.

#### Question: If I provide `V_target` from the microcontroller to the J-Link Plus, does that mean the I/O voltage levels on the serial wire debug pins are reduced to 1.8V?

I'm looking at this (arguably overpriced for what it is) `V_target` adapter, and trying to understand the real benefit I get from it: https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/accessories/adapters/supply-adapter/

It appears that it would just allow me to not require an additional wire for `V_target` coming out of my device.

J-Link Plus product page: https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/j-link-plus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

J-Link has buffers (or level converters) that you can provide with any voltage between 1.8 and 5V. This voltage can come from anywhere - from the target, from an LDO on the J-Link side, from another PSU. It hardly matters as long as the logic levels of the target MCU match the logic levels of J-Link buffers.

You could even inject power via Vtref to the target board (depending on the exact design).

The linked adapter does exactly what is advertized - it allows to generate the voltages on the J-Link side and get rid of one wire connecting to the target board.